# Form a word from a scrambled letters in java

Tags: scramble

i'm doing a game project,in which we have to form words dynamically with the given set of letters... the given set of letters may contain duplicate also.. while forming words we can use a letter from a given set of letters for any number of times(say for twice or thrice)... help me with an algorithm to form all possible meaningful words from the given set

Thank u all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficent word scramble algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784303/efficent-word-scramble-algorithm)

Comment: I don't think so - that question had to do with maximizing the words in a particular ordering - this question is more about cheating at scrabble

Comment: Find subsets of your set and permutations of all subsets and match it with a dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to create every possible ordering of letters, then compare each one of them to your dictionary.

You can refine it a bit by storing the dictionary in a data structure which facilitates quick lookups. (hash table, tree, etc)  I've been meaning to implement a 28-ary tree for quick dictionary word access, but haven't got around to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for a crossword solver many moons ago. I basically took a dictionary file and modified it so it looked like:

```
aardvark:aaadkrr
albatross:aablorsst
```

Then, for a given set of letters, I could just sort them and use something like:

```
grep ':{sorted letters}$' mywords.txt | sed 's/:.*$//'
```

and that would give me the candidate words.

You'll have to wrap some permutation/combination code around that if you're looking for words that can use less than the full set, but the algorithm given was very efficient.

For Java, I'd consider either maintaining a hash table in-memory (assuming you have space) or using an external database where the lookup keys are the sorted varaiations, allowing duplicates of course, since `pore` and `rope` would both come from `eorp`.

While my `grep`-based solution was fine for my own purposes, you probably don't want to rely on external tools and sub-processes in a robust application.